# Write to a file using JSR223 Assertion

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jsr223

Is it possible to write data to a file inside a `JSR223 Assertion` using javascript as the language? How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is somehow possible.

Due to security reasons you cannot access file system in JavaScript, but according to [JSR223 specification](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223) is is not only possible to call scripts from Java but you can do the opposite thing - call Java from scripts, in your case from JavaScript. The relevant code would be:

```
var writer = new java.io.PrintWriter('your_file.txt')
writer.write('hello')
writer.close()
```

Reference material and code snippets:

- [Using Java From Scripts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use Groovy (and check cache checkbox) to follow best-practices:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

It's just this:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new java.io.File("/data/jmeter/test.log"), 
     "String to append", 
     "UTF-8", 
      true);
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to use Groovy, but I know nothing about the language and my javascript is quite complex. But thank you anyway!

Comment: I've found that groovy scripts don't work well with Windows paths that have backslashes in them.

Comment: Don't use backslashes then, use forward slashes. I've found in most cases Windows is perfectly happy with c:/temp/jmeter/bin/ and so on. And it makes coding easier.